# Problem with PIC18F45K50's ANSELE register

Tags: assembly, pic, pic18, mplab-x

I am trying to make a code for PIC18F45K50, I am trying to use `PORTE` as digital input, that means I have to clear `ANSELE` register which controls this pin behavior

Working on MPLABX 3.30 i tried this line of code:

```
clrf ANSELE
```

to clear the register, and I also tried setting the bits of the register individually, but when testing on MPLABX debugger, no matter what I do, the instruction just doesn't do anything and the code goes on. I wish someone can help me or bring me some information about how i can enable this register to be modified in MPLABx

The code im working on is made in ASM

Comment: Try to elaborate what you're trying to do, I mean what do you expect that the code does, also add your implementation.

Comment: Your MPLABx is pretty old. It' not the issue, but maybe update to v5.3. And please show more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANSELE has address 0x0F5F so isn't direct addressable because it is not part of access RAM.
Check datasheet PIC18(L)F2X/45K50, FIGURE 6-5: **DATA MEMORY MAP FOR PIC18(L)F2X/45K50 DEVICES** for more information.

Load first the proper BSR value to access these registers, like:

```
   MOVLB   high ANSELE 
   CLRF    ANSELE
```

Or use MPLAB assembler directive like...

```
   BANKSEL ANSELE 
   CLRF    ANSELE
```